# Excel - Force rows to follow pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, data-validation

I have an excel sheet of data which I am trying to sort so it follows a pattern (in order to automate the filling of a second sheet). The first sheet in question looks like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jayNw.png)

So the pattern which repeats is "Body Type, Robot 1, Robot 2, Robot 3, Robot 4, Total Time"

I have highlighted the cells that are causing the problem - sometimes the same data is repeated, or certain cells have been missed so the pattern is not followed.

I would like to delete the repeated cells, but in the case where data is missed, I would like to delete that specific block, from "Body Type" to "Total Time".

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is likely you will need VBA for this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I agree - but I am struggling to come up with something that will  cycle through because I have a lot of data (for example 37,000 columns for 5 days of data but this can also vary). Just looking for an example that could help me get the data into the right pattern. If this is not possible I will look into SQL because the data is sent from an online server to Excel using SQL.

Comment: (1) You have 37,000 ***columns**?*  Seriously?  (Or do you mean rows?)  (2) Can you *describe* your problem more clearly, giving clear examples as text?  Explain the role of Columns A and B.  (I suggest you use a smaller number of key (Column C) values, like “S”, “A” and “M”.)  Show sample inputs and desired outputs.  (3) In what sense is Row 14 a problem?  (4) I guess that Rows 23 and 24 are a problem in the sense that there is no “Robot 4” value (row) for “00:03”. Am I right? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.